# Specifying the order of output using awk

Tags: unix, awk

I have the following file called testfile, with the following contents:

```
{"items":[{"ogit\/_created on":1413388512511,"\/environmentType":"PROD","\/soxRelevant":"true","\/environmentName":"dbVertical"}]}
```

I used the following awk command to get the values for soxRelevant, environment type and environment name.

```
cat test file | tr -d '"' | awk 'BEGIN {RS=","; FS=":"; ORS=",";} /soxRelevant/ {print $2}; /environmentType/ {print $2}; /environmentName/ {print $2};'
```

The output was as follows

```
PROD,true,dbVertical,
```

However I want the soxRelevant output first followed by environment type then environment name, as specified in the awk command:

I want the output to be:

```
true, PROD, dbVertical
```

How do I do this?

Comment: It would be good to note you have never accepted any answer so far. Consider doing so if you want people to help you.

Comment: How do I accept answer, I don't see option for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could push the elements to an array then print them in the END block:

```
awk 'BEGIN {RS=ORS=","; FS=":"}
     /soxRelevant/ {a[1]=$2} 
     /environmentType/ {a[2]=$2} 
     /environmentName/ {a[3]=$2}
     END{for(n=1;n<=3;++n)print a[n]}'
```

Comment: This works, however is there a way to print out the whole array without using a for loop, something along the lines a[*]?

Comment: Not in awk, no. You could do something like that in perl although I would suggest a completely different approach using a JSON parser in that case.